# SetValue is not working for mui Select with React hook form

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I want to set the value when page loads and change the value if I want to update, its a multiSelect

```
const options= [
  { label: 'Apple', value: 'Apple' },
  { label: 'Grape', value: 'Grape' }
]
```

```
useEffect(()=>
setValue('fruits' 'apple')
},[])
```

```
<Select  {...register('fruits')} defaultValue={defaultValue ?? ''}
    onChange={handleChange} value={value} multiple={multiple} >
        {options?.map((option, index) => (
          <MenuItem key={index} value={option.value}>{option.label}</MenuItem>
        ))}
      </Select>
```

Handle Change function

```
const [value, setValue] = useState([]);

const handleChange = (event) => {    
    setValue(event.target.value)
    onChange && onChange(name, event.target.value);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you need state while using react-hook-form? You can track the values with `watch` from `useFormContext` or `useWatch`. From react-hook-form

In your code register('fruits') gives you an object that has onChange. You are overriding this onChange with your handleChange

Comment: Because its a multi Select